# Difference between getResources(R.string.hello_world) and R.string.hello_world

Tags: android, resources

Which is the difference between using:

```
getResources().getText(R.string.hello_world)
```

and:

```
R.string.hello_world
```

The second way, should return an int object. I've just tried:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getText(R.string.hello_world), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

And:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.hello_world, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

And seems to work in both ways.

Thanks for help!

Comment: The second does return an int. There are 2 versions of `makeText` - one takes an int resource id and the second takes a charsequence. You are calling 2 different methods above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.hello_world, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
```

calls

`Toast.makeText(Context, int, int)` and it is "translated" like

```
public static Toast makeText(Context context, int resId, int duration)  
                                throws Resources.NotFoundException {    
   return makeText(context, context.getResources().getText(resId), duration); 
}
```

all in all it is equal to your first `makeText`

Comment: Well, this explains why the second way dosen't work on Notification Builder .setTitle! Thanks a lot, next time i'll check better ;)

Answer (score 2):

`getResources().getText(R.string.hello_world)` : will return String.. 
And

`R.string.hello_world`: will return integer (reference location of objects).

And makeToast() method is available for both parameters.

If you passed it string it treat is message.

if you passed it any integer it will treat it as a reference location of String and control will find that String. If No string will available with provided integer then it will throw exception. (`ResourceNotFoundException`)